# Personal sorting system in the finder's windows

Tags: macos, finder, sort

Is there a way to use a personal sorting system in the finder's windows ? I don't want to sort the files and folders using the "Labels" (because of the colors). I just want to have the list ordered the way I want...

Is this possible ?

Comment: In what view? In icon view, you can put them in whatever order you want. In the other views, not so much.

Comment: Indeed, obviously not in the icon view.

Comment: the way you want as in drag & drop to change the order? then probably no. But you can change the arrangement of lists by going to View > Arrange By.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make a custom sort order using Spotlight Comments. Show the Comments column in your Finder window (`View > Show View Options`), then enter Spotlight Comments into your files (`File > Get Info`) so that they sort in the order you want. You could also use these comments for Spotlight searches and smart folders.

[image: Custom Sort with Spotlight Comments]

You can use Automator to add the same comment to a whole batch of files by creating an Automator Service (for contextual menu) or Application (for drag & drop) and using the "Set Spotlight Comments for Finder Items" action. Make sure to change "Service receives selected" to `files or folders`. To have Automator ask you what text to use for the comment, show the Options for the "Set Spotlight Comments" action and check `Show this action when the workflow runs`.

[image: Automator Workflow: Batch Comment]

Comment: By the way, I've heard that Spotlight Comments are stored in `.DS_Store` files, so be careful deleting them if you use this trick! (:

Comment: How can I use more than 1 such column? :)