# How to have a custom (or no) sort order in Finder windows

Tags: finder, macos

Similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30147/personal-sorting-system-in-the-finders-windows), that has been answered, I have an end user that wants to sort folders in a particular order that doesn't really match any of the basic sorting methods.  She doesn't like the list view, instead preferring the column view, so that answer wouldn't really work for her.

She would like to sort folders that are named after months in the order they would appear on a calendar.  Basically like this:

- Work January
- Work February
- Work March
- Work April
- .....

Normally I'd say there's no way to do this, at least without using tricks similar to the answer of the question I linked to above, which are in my opinion outside the scope for most basic users.  However, at one point she had a folder set up similar to this.  It could have very well been a bug or anomaly but I'm trying to exhaust all options before ruling it as such.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to your question?

Comment: @SystemsRebooter - I'm pretty sure I passed along Buscars answer to the end user and it was good enough for her

Answer (score 2):

If you simply put numbers (for the months) in front of the folders names they will be sorted.

If you prefer then use the Folder Action and Automator to do that automatically, for the folder containing the sub folders with the months names (numbers).